# How to read the latest dataset using fread in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to:

- read the latest data from my data folder. I have the same data but at different time stamps.

#### UPDATED ACCORDING TO THE SUGGESTION IN THE COMMENT

For example:

As you can see my first data was produced on date 20230524 at 10:48

```
log_metrics202305241048
# A tibble: 10 × 9
   `App name`                  Total number of view…¹ Total number of view…² Total number of view…³
   <chr>                                        <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>
 1 animals_to_groups                               22                     21                     19
 2 cage_randomiser                                 34                     33                     30
 3 combo_cor                                       19                     18                     18
 4 crispr_screen_viz                               23                     81                     21
 5 dep_map_bem                                      5                     12                      5
 6 dtp_browser_prod                                 7                      6                      7
 7 flat                                            67                     66                     67
 8 growth_rate_explorer                            42                     47                     41
 9 moprospector                                     3                      3                      2
10 translatability_single_gene                     22                     43                     21
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Total number of views by unique visitors`,
#   ²​`Total number of views by number of logs`,
#   ³​`Total number of views by unique visitor, over 30 seconds`
# ℹ 5 more variables: `Total number of views by logs, over 30 seconds` <dbl>,
#   `Average time spent per app (minutes) by logs` <dbl>, `Maxium duration (in minutes)` <time>,
#   `Minimum duration (in minutes` <time>, `Total number of views over an hour` <dbl>
>
```

This is my second dataset which clearly was produced on 2023 05 204 at 10:51

```
   log_metrics202305241051
# A tibble: 10 × 9
   `App name`                  Total number of view…¹ Total number of view…² Total number of view…³
   <chr>                                        <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>
 1 animals_to_groups                               22                     21                     19
 2 cage_randomiser                                 34                     33                     30
 3 combo_cor                                       19                     18                     18
 4 crispr_screen_viz                               23                     81                     21
 5 dep_map_bem                                      5                     12                      5
 6 dtp_browser_prod                                 7                      6                      7
 7 flat                                            67                     66                     67
 8 growth_rate_explorer                            42                     47                     41
 9 moprospector                                     3                      3                      2
10 translatability_single_gene                     22                     43                     21
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Total number of views by unique visitors`,
#   ²​`Total number of views by number of logs`,
#   ³​`Total number of views by unique visitor, over 30 seconds`
# ℹ 5 more variables: `Total number of views by logs, over 30 seconds` <dbl>,
#   `Average time spent per app (minutes) by logs` <dbl>, `Maxium duration (in minutes)` <time>,
#   `Minimum duration (in minutes` <time>, `Total number of views over an hour` <dbl>
```

Now, I want to read the latest dataset, which is the first one, produced on 10:08. However, as a background, I want to produce monthly datasets, but because I am trying to do this in the future, I will now use the datetime stamps. Thus, I believe it is better to use both, date and time, to be be recognised and picked.

I am using the data.table::fread to read the data because this it reads it very quick.

Now I want to program this code `data.table::fread('data/generated_metrics/log_visits_ with the latest date.csv')` to read the latest dataset found in data/generated_metrics/ folder where all these log_visists data stamped are sitting.

Is there a way to programmatically do this using fread function to read the latest data set? I am also open for alternative functions for reading my latest data.

Comment: Use a better datetime format in your file names, e.g., `log_metrics_202305241008`. Then you can just sort the file names (see `help("list.files")` for getting all files in a directory). With your current format, you need to extract the datetime information from the file name and parse it in R before you can sort.

Comment: FYI, I don't know of any file-reader that has an argument ala *"when multiple files with this pattern are found, parse the filename and get me the latest"*. I don't even know of any that can do that based on the file's timestamp itself (which is more native). In general, choosing which file(s) to open must be done _before_ calling `fread` or `read.csv` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use `as.POSIXct` to parse the filenames. *Edit*: since you added the use of a subdir, we need to expand `list.files` a little, and then use `basename` to work on just the filenames ...

```r
files <- list.files(path = "my/data/directory", pattern  ="log_metrics.*",
                    full.names = TRUE)
# files <- c("my/data/directory/log_metrics24_May_2023_10_03", "my/data/directory/log_metrics24_May_2023_10_08")
basename(files)
# [1] "log_metrics24_May_2023_10_03" "log_metrics24_May_2023_10_08"
as.POSIXct(basename(files), format = "log_metrics%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M")
# [1] "2023-05-24 10:03:00 EDT" "2023-05-24 10:08:00 EDT"
files[which.max(as.POSIXct(basename(files), format = "log_metrics%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M"))]
# [1] "my/data/directory/log_metrics24_May_2023_10_08"
fread(files[which.max(as.POSIXct(basename(files), format = "log_metrics%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M"))])
```

If your filename prefix varies, one hack (that may or may not work) is to strip everything leading up to the first number (note no more use of `basename`).

```r
sub("^[^0-9]*", "", files)
# [1] "24_May_2023_10_03" "24_May_2023_10_08"
as.POSIXct(sub("^[^0-9]*", "", files), format = "%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M")
# [1] "2023-05-24 10:03:00 EDT" "2023-05-24 10:08:00 EDT"
files[which.max(as.POSIXct(sub("^[^0-9]*", "", files), format = "%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M"))]
# [1] "my/data/directory/log_metrics24_May_2023_10_08"
```

If you aren't familiar with `as.POSIXct`'s use of `%`-codes, see [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

Comment: I have updated the code as suggested in the comment

Comment: Okay, my method stands, you just need to change the `format=` used. Or you can just sort the filenames, since now the date is more easily sorted.

Comment: I am a bit confused, where to I pass the path? to pick up the latest file?

Comment: `fread(files[which.max(...)])`? or `latestfile <- files[which.max(...)]; fread(latestfile)`

Comment: or are you asking how to look in a different directory for your files?

Comment: yes, so I am storing the datasets into a data folder directory. I am hoping to be clear. at the moment I am reading data.table::fread(path = "path/to/folder/.csv" )

Comment: `files <- list.files(path="my/data/directory/", pattern="log_metrics.*", full.names=TRUE)`, similar to what is in my answer. See [`?list.files`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) for those args and more.

Comment: hmm, so, I have 2 datasets with two different  date time stamps, and want to read only one file, which is the latest. Because if I read only with list.files then I get all of them. Yet, I need the latest. So I assume it should be something like latestfile <- fread(list.files[which.max('path/to/folder', pattern = "log_metrics.*", full_name = TRUE)]) ?

Comment: `list.files` is a _function_, do not index it with `[`; similarly, `which.max` is also a function but it does not know anything about paths or patterns, do not confuse the two. Please try my code. By creating the `files` character vector, you are not reading in the files, you are just listing the files (ergo the function name `list.files`); once you have that vector, you can determine which of the file names is latest based on parsing the date out of the filename.

Comment: it seems I get errors. Is it because I have data with date formats as log_metrics202305241051 ? I get error - > # files <- c("log_metrics24_May_2023_10_03", "log_metrics24_May_2023_10_08")
> as.POSIXct(files, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M")
[1] NA NA NA NA
> basename(files)
[1] "log_metrics202305241048.csv" "log_metrics202305241051.csv"
[3] "log_metrics202305241103.csv" "log_metrics202305241106.csv"
> as.POSIXct(basename(files), format = "log_metrics%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M")
[1] NA NA NA NA

Comment: it has worked with this format :
files <- list.files(path = "data/generated_metrics", pattern  ="log_metrics.*",
                    full.names = TRUE)
as.POSIXct(basename(files), format = "log_metrics%Y%m%d%H%M"), if you do update than it would go with consistency of the code

Comment: I'm glad the method worked for you!